# redis: ошибка при множественных коннектах-дисконнектах, которые происходят с частотой в 1 секунду

Tags: linux, redis

Хочу потестить устойчивость работы локального redis сервера, написал простенькие скрипты на js и php

javascript:

```
setInterval(function()
{

$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/connector.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "post",
        async: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus)
        {

        },
        error: function(data, textStatus)
        {
        }
    });
 }, 1000);
```

connector.php:

```
$redis_host = "ip";
$redis_port = "port";
$redis_password = "password";
$redis_ttl = null; 

$r = new Redis();

try
{
    $r->connect($redis_host, $redis_port, 2);
} 
catch(RedisException $e)
{
    $f = fopen("!report", "a");
                    
    if(flock($f, LOCK_EX))
    fwrite($f, $_GET["ex"].": ".$e."\n\n");

    fclose($f);        
}   

$r->close();
```

затем открываю несколько вкладок и с каждой запускаю. Некоторое произвольное время все нормально коннектится-стопарится-коннектится-стопарится, а потом в лог (иногда) падает вот такая штука:

> RedisException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.
> in \connector.php:13
> Stack trace:
> #0 \connector.php(13): Redis->connect('ip', 'port', 2)
> #1 {main}

А затем все дальше нормально работает

Канал 200 мб, сервак не мощный (NAS), но абсолютно не загруженный, для чистоты эксперимента, только редис там крутится и еще пару служб, которые не мешаются. Можно ли как то с моей проблемой справиться, что делать?

Спасибо

UPD. Redis сервер вначале поднял как штатное ПО Synology, затем развернуд Docker и в контейнере запустил - проблема везде остается